# Max post size ignored by Wildfly 10

Tags: post, configuration, size, max, wildfly-10

I have a problem with uploading files larger than 10MB on Wildfly 10.0.0.Final. Here you have my standalone.xml file

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0">
            <buffer-cache name="default" />
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"
                    redirect-socket="https" max-post-size="31457280"/>
                <https-listener name="default-ssl" security-realm="SSLRealm"
                    socket-binding="https" max-post-size="31457280"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content" />
<!--                    <filter-ref name="server-header" /> -->
<!--                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header" /> -->
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config />
                <websockets />
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content" />
            </handlers>
            <filters>
                <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server"
                    header-value="WildFly/10" />
                <response-header name="x-powered-by-header"
                    header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1" />
            </filters>
        </subsystem>
```

And here it is the exception I get when I try to upload a file larger than 10MB:

```
2017-07-04 10:59:28,496 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter] (default task-24) Forwarding to error page from request [/manuals] due to exception [java.io.IOException: UT000020: Connection terminated as request was larger than 10485760]: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: UT000020: Connection terminated as request was larger than 10485760
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.parseFormData(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:764)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getParameter(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:636)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: UT000020: Connection terminated as request was larger than 10485760
    at io.undertow.conduits.FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.checkMaxSize(FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.java:168)
    at io.undertow.conduits.FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.read(FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.java:229)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.read(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:127)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSourceChannel.read(DetachableStreamSourceChannel.java:209)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$ReadDispatchChannel.read(HttpServerExchange.java:2231)
    at org.xnio.channels.Channels.readBlocking(Channels.java:294)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.readIntoBuffer(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:170)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.read(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:146)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.read(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:133)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.MultiPartParserDefinition$MultiPartUploadHandler.parseBlocking(MultiPartParserDefinition.java:212)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.parseFormData(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:762)
    ... 43 more

2017-07-04 10:59:28,700 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter] (default task-30) Forwarding to error page from request [/manuals] due to exception [java.io.IOException: UT000020: Connection terminated as request was larger than 10485760]: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: UT000020: Connection terminated as request was larger than 10485760
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.parseFormData(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:764)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getParameter(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:636)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: UT000020: Connection terminated as request was larger than 10485760
    at io.undertow.conduits.FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.checkMaxSize(FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.java:168)
    at io.undertow.conduits.FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.read(FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.java:229)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.read(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:127)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSourceChannel.read(DetachableStreamSourceChannel.java:209)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$ReadDispatchChannel.read(HttpServerExchange.java:2231)
    at org.xnio.channels.Channels.readBlocking(Channels.java:294)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.readIntoBuffer(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:170)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.read(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:146)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.read(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:133)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.MultiPartParserDefinition$MultiPartUploadHandler.parseBlocking(MultiPartParserDefinition.java:212)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.parseFormData(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:762)
    ... 43 more
```

Why does Wildfly complains about the 10MB limit although the limit is set to 30MB in the configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
It was a problem with the configuration of Spring and not of Wildfly. I leave this answer here in case it might be helpful for our descendants... :-)

Comment: As I said, it was a setting in the Spring configuration files and not a in Wildfly configuration files. I can't help you right now, though, as I am on holiday and don't have the laptop with me. Send me a bump on Monday and I'll help you.

Comment: Bump (even though it is not monday)

Comment: your descendants are disappointed with their ancestors attention spans...

Comment: There was a parameter in the spring configuration file named max-post-size with the limit for th POST calls